# Filtering results from Realm

Tags: swift, realm

I've saved data of coordinates in Realm, and I am trying to separate the results into 2 separate `Array`s or `CLLocationDegrees` (latitude and longitude), but I can't figure out how. I am printing the retrieved results, so I know they've been saved/retrieved successfully - console output:

```
[0] Data {
    latitude = 37.33454847;
    longitude = -122.03611286;
    }, 
[1] Data {
    latitude = 37.33454218;
    longitude = -122.03638578;
    }, 
//and continues...
```

ViewController Class (loadLocations function)

```
func loadLocations() {
    theLocations = realm.objects(Data.self)
    print(theLocations)
    //This function gets called in the viewDidLoad()
}
```

Data Class

```
class Data: Object {
    @objc dynamic var latitude: CLLocationDegrees()
    @objc dynamic var longitude: CLLocationDegrees()
}
```

How would I separate latitude and longitude into their own `Array`s or `CLLocationDegrees`? Or even an `Array` of `CLLocationDegrees` to then cover with  a polyline overlay?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: same object 2 arrays ? or 2 object each one has an array ? explain more please

Comment: @Tobi I think same object, 2 `Array`s? I basically want latitude and longitude to each have their own `Array`, but don't know which would be better, 1 object or 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way:

Realm is not setup in my project so i am doing with struct.

Struct of Location:

```
struct Locations {

    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
}

    // Your Realm result Array
    var theLocations = [Locations]()

    // Adding Dummy Data into theLocations Array
    theLocations.append(Locations(latitude: 37.33454847, longitude: -122.03611286))
    theLocations.append(Locations(latitude: 37.33454218, longitude: -122.03638578))

    // latitude and longitude to store values
    var arrLat = [Double]()
    var arrLong = [Double]()

    // Looping  through theLocations Array and Seperate latitude and longitude to append to array
    theLocations.forEach{ location in
        arrLat.append(location.latitude)
        arrLong.append(location.longitude)
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I can see how to append the locations to the array, but the problem is that the data I am trying to put in these `Array`s are `: Results<Data>!` and I need to figure out how to access both parts ie `latitude` and `longitude` _of_ that data (apologies for edits, not great at explaining)

Comment: @TsGDev You are not able to get `theLocations.latitude` in forEach?

Comment: Oh, I think I've gone about it the wrong way, apologies let me retry it!

Comment: @TsGDev it should work for you. I have setup Realm in my project and tried and it's working.

Comment: YES! Thank you! The `.forEach` was the keyword I was looking for, thank you very much!!

Comment: @TsGDev Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can map your `Results<Data>` to `CLLocationCoordinate2D`s and then put them in an array:

```
let results = realm.objects(Data.self) // btw, Data is a terrible name. You should call it "Coordinate"
let arrayOfCoordinates = Array(results.map { CLLocationCoorinate2D(latitude: $0.latitude, longitude: $0.longitude) })
// arrayOfCoordinates is of type [CLLocationCoordinate2D]
```

However, you are not really using Realm to its full potential this way. Realm `Results` are supposed to be accessed lazily (i.e. only when you need them). If you are converting the whole thing to an array immediately, you are basically loading everything into memory. I recommend that you use the lazy collection returned by `map` directly:

```
let lazyCollection = results.map { CLLocationCoorinate2D(latitude: $0.latitude, longitude: $0.longitude) }
```

Comment: Amazing, all working now! Thank you for your help + advise on changing Data name